# Circuit to work around optocoupler's output voltage limit

Tags: opto-isolator

I have an application that calls for an H11D1 optocoupler. This part has a maxmimum output voltage of 300V. The optocouplers I have on hand have a much lower output voltage rating.

Is there a way to use another part, such as an appropriately rated transistor, to allow the use of an optocoupler with a lower output voltage rating?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very big resistor in series with the octocoupler.Find the minimum dark current and the voltage rating of the optocoupler and connect the optocoupler in series with a resistor \$R = \frac{300-V_{optrt}}{I_{darkmin}}\$

Comment: Your answer would apply to the input (LED) side of the optocoupler.  I think the OP is concerned with the output (transistor) side.

Comment: @PeterBennett perhaps you're confused?

Comment: The OP mentions "output voltage rating" three times in his question.

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes the phototransistor is at the output of the optocoupler

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a transistor, here's a solution. This is called cascoding.

[image]